# Forwarding gsuite group mail to pubsub / cloud function using service account / admin console

Tags: gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-workspace

I am an gsuite/gcp admin and want to forward all emails sent to a group into pubsub without involving any personal accounts.

The process describe here fits my need except for the authentication part. I would instead like to make the forwarding bound to a group and not a user.
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html#4

Comment: Where do you perform the process? On a function? A VM?

Comment: The process uses gcp services and is not manually set up. I plan to do the actual coding in cloud functions. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/intelligent-gmail-processing/index.html#2

Comment: Did you try to put your Cloud Function service account as manager of your Google Group and then perform an API call with the service account access token as Bearer token in the Authorization header?